# Meaning of: if it is the injury he is expecting

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> We play a very, very emotional game,” Seattle linebacker Bobby Wagner said. “I think sometimes you have to allow people to have their emotions. I don’t think nothing of it. **I think he has a long road ahead of him if it is the injury he is expecting**.

<sup>(Quote from [a news story about Earl Thomas breaking his leg](https://www.foxnews.com/sports/seattle-seahawks-player-breaks-leg-sends-parting-message-to-team))</sup>

What does the sentence in bold mean? The “if it is the injury he is expecting” is the most confusing part. Would you rephrase it for me please?

Comment: Please read through [How to Write a Better Title](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/how-can-i-write-a-better-title-for-my-ell-question) on meta – particularly Section 3.

Answer (score 2):

> I think he has a long road ahead of him if it is the injury he is
>   expecting.

I will start on the second half

> if it is the injury he is
>   expecting.

The player has had an injury, they haven't yet had an official diagnosis, but the player (and everyone else) has seen this so often they know what it is

> I think he has a long road ahead of him

a "long road ahead" is an idiom/ metaphor and it literally means "he has a long way to travel", which effectively means "a lot of work to do, and it will take a lot of time".

So to put it all together:
**The player has had an injury (we all think we know what it is) and there is going to be a lot of healing  and physio therapy and training required to regain his peak performance.**